# MySQL: Query design issue

Tags: php, mysql

My tables are like this:

**Table 1 (students)**
[image: Table 1]

**Table 2 (results)**

[image: Table 2]

I want to select all students from Table 1 `students` who have 4 results in the `results` table. I tried this query, but with no success:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students
WHERE gender =  'm'
AND (SELECT COUNT( result ) AS count
FROM results
INNER JOIN students ON results.stuID = students.stuID
WHERE result !=0
) =4
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `alias` for table also -

```
SELECT * 
FROM students as a
WHERE gender =  'm'
AND (SELECT COUNT(result) AS count
FROM results as b
WHERE b.stuID = a.stuID AND
(result!=0 OR result IS NOT NULL OR result!='')
) = 4
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Comment: Working perfect! Thanks, I will accept your answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite your query by using join and `HAVING` clause to check the count for each student group ,This can be done without using the subquery which sometimes affects on performance

```
SELECT s.*,COUNT(*) AS count
FROM students s
INNER JOIN results r ON r.stuID = s.stuID
WHERE r.result !=0
GROUP BY s.stuID 
HAVING count =4
ORDER BY s.rank ASC
```

Comment: As far as optimized query is concern its the best +1

Answer (score 1):

um, that's a little convoluted.
the where clause should come after the subquery, and the subquery still needs to be JOINed back to the main query.

something like

```
SELECT * FROM students 
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(result),results.stuID as count FROM results WHERE result != 0) as result_count
ON result_count.stuID = students.stuID
WHERE result_count.count =4 AND students.gender = 'm'
ORDER BY rank ASC
```